# How to add a custom Svg Icon as Activity Indicator in react native flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-svg, activity-indicator

I want to change the default activity indicator with my custom SVG Icon in React Native Flatlist

```
<FlatList
 showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
 data={videos}
 refreshControl={
  <RefreshControl
   refreshing={getLatestVideos?.isFetching}
   onRefresh={refresh}
   colors={['#9AD3F4']}
   progressBackgroundColor={'#005594'}
  />
 }
 renderItem={({item, index}) => (<ListingItems />) }
/>
```

I was only able to change the color of the default indicator but What I want is to add my custom SVG as an indicator